# MySQL Query - a bit tricky

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i'm having the following tables:

```
USERS:                               ITEMS

user_id  name    always_show         id   user_id  name
--------------------------           --------------------------------
1        Joe                         1    1        Apple   
2        Sam                         2    1        Banana
3        Walter  1                   3    2        Cherry
```

i'm doing this query:

```
SELECT * FROM
  users Inner Join
  items On users.user_id = items.user_id
```

The question is: how can i add all other users which have the flag always_show set?

Comment: what are the relations between the tables? 1:1? 1:n? n:1? n:m? You're using an inner join, so I harazrd it's a 1:1 relation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i hope i understand your question :-) try `UNION`

```
SELECT u.* FROM users u
INNER JOIN items i ON u.user_id = i.user_id

UNION ALL SELECT * FROM users WHERE always_show = 1
```

Comment: @Fuxi i forgot the select in the union... try again!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
INNER JOIN items On users.user_id = items.user_id
UNION
SELECT * 
FROM users 
LEFT OUTER JOIN items On users.user_id = items.user_id AND users.always_show = 1
```

Comment: this seems almost correct, but i'm getting duplicate records:
joe, joe, sam, joe, sam, walter

Comment: my bad.. had an `ALL` in there that wasn't needed. Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM
  users Inner Join
  items On users.user_id = items.user_id where Users.always_set = 1
```